# Is $PARTITION mandatory?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2, database-partitioning

I have a big table which I want to partition by date (the first of each month) since most queries contain date range.
I know that I can use $PARTITION to ask the relevant partition but since the range can cross partitions I was wondering if MS SQL knows not to search in invalid partitions if It's not specified?

I'm using MS SQL 2008 r2

Comment: Of course it will search only in those partitions where your data exists.

Comment: Thanks Girgi. That's was i thought. But if I decide to to partition by month part, meaning by int 1-12, then I'll have to use $PARTITION, right?

Comment: If your partition function is on Date it will not use partition. Sorry `$PARTITION` didn't use this.